# in python django if else not working either showing both or only the first field is showing

Tags: python, django, database

I am working in Django python and written these two statements to check if email or username exists in database  or not but the message is coming from both email is taken and username is taken but I want it should show it seperately if enter any one if I give input in my sign up form

```
  if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                # error_message = ''
                email_error = ('', 'Email is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()]
                messages.success(request, email_error)


  elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                username_error = ('', 'Username is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()]
                messages.success(request, username_error)
                return redirect('/register/')
```

Comment: It's not possible for the `if` and `elif` to both be true.  The messages must be coming from some other code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: wait I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

```
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    # error_message = ''
    email_error = ('', 'Email is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()]
    messages.success(request, email_error)
    return redirect('/register/')


elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
    username_error = ('', 'Username is taken. ')[User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()]
    messages.success(request, username_error)
    return redirect('/register/')
```

just redirect from both condition

Comment: wait have to check but have a doubt will it work after a return statement

Comment: yup it will u have to just call it again have u tried ???

Comment: sorry for late comment I tried it didnt work only email is working username not

Comment: hello so u want to check both email and username at a same time ??

Comment: i have a html registration form over there ane fields are username email password and submit button and this is a part of views.py and i want to check indivudual email or username exists or not so if i only enter username and click submit it should show email is taken or if i enter username and click submit it should say username is taken if exists

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the Or behavior, (email exists, username exists or both) you'll need to do the following:

```py
email_taken = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()
username_taken = User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()

if email_taken:
    messages.error("Email is taken.")

if username_taken:
    messages.error("Username is taken.")

if email_taken or username_taken:
    return redirect('/register/')
```

Comment: What's not working? are you not getting the errors in the test cases? How are you displaying the messages?

Comment: It saying only email is taken on username input also I am displaying messages on html page by bootstrap alert

Comment: Try to learn how to debug, does the `username_taken` yields True when used in an interactive shell?
in your HTML template, are you iterating over all the errors?